# Shape Files (Free downloads) for districts of the world

Tags: data-request, geospatial, geocoding

I am looking for shape files(polygons data) of all the districts in the world. I can find few files from different sources for districts of one country but I need one (updated) file that have all the districts in the world OR one reliable source from where I can get files may be one per country. Please help me find.

PS: shape files for countries and regions are easily available but not required in my case and by world districts I mean district of all the cities or states in the world. like New York consists 27 Congressional Districts.

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 ways to do it

1) Download shapefiles from [here](http://www.gadm.org/country) for cities boundaries. A single file  for each country.

2) Use [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/geo/id/%3aplace_id) to get the coordinates and polygons for each city.

3) Use [wikimapia](http://wikimapia.org/api/) for the same thing such as Twitter API

Comment: The GADM data is restricted to private/non-commercial use.

Comment: Thanks Anastasios Ventouris. Your first option worked for me.

Comment: Great. But, when one of the answers are OK for you, you shall choose them as a "best answer". It is a "tick" next to the answer post. You can also, upvote the post as well. Just avoid to comment with a new answer here.